# css show center center transform

Tags: css, transform

Does anyone know how to css transform a 16px by 16px img `display: none` from the center out?

**HTML**

```
<center>
<br>
<div class="t"></div>
</center>
```

**CSS**

```
.t {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background: green;
    display: block;
    }

.a {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 5s;
    transform-origin: center center;
    }
```

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.t').addClass('a');},1000);
```

What I have right now shows from the center horizontally but vertically it seems to appear from the top.

**BTW: I'm not able to use Jquery scale in this case**

Answer (score 1):

Solved: It must also be moved x and y with translate

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
.t {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    }

.a {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) translateX(-4px) translateY(-4px);
    -moz-transform: scale(2) translateX(-4px) translateY(-4px);
    -o-transform: scale(2) translateX(-4px) translateY(-4px);
    transform-origin:4px 4px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a container and then absolutely position the container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="t"></div>
</div>

.container {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-8px -8px 0 0;
}
.t {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background: green;
    display: block;
    }

.a {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 5s;
    transform-origin:center center;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwqVX/1/)

Comment: Why do you include a rotate(0)? Also, there is *no* need for a container

Comment: All I added was the container HTML/CSS, the rest of the code is from the OP.